# How do I redraw a path using D3.js methodology?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I can't seem to get the .enter() and .exit for a path to work correctly. For the code below, everytime I try to redraw the path, it keeps the old path.

I would venture to guess that what's wrong is the .attr("d",stepline(csProg)).  I was thinking it should be something more like .attr("d",function(d) { stepline(d); }) or something like that, but I couldn't get it to work.  Any suggestions?

```
function drawCloseChart(mysvg,mydata,cx1,cx2,cy1,cy2,oq)
{

var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([360*60, 390*60]).range([cx1, cx2]), 
    y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,oq]).range([cy1,cy2]),
    z = d3.scale.category10();


var targetg = mysvg.append("svg:g");

    //code to draw x-axis
    //code to draw y-axis

var stepline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.time); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.val); })
    .interpolate("step-after");

var chartData = [];
chartData.redraw = function()
{


    var cpg = cprog.selectAll("path").data(csProg);
    cpg.enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d",stepline(csProg))
        .attr("fill","none")
        .attr("stroke-width","2")
        .attr("stroke","black");

    cpg.exit().remove();        

}
chartData.redraw();
return chartData;
}
```

And later in the code I would call (or something to this effect):

setInterval(function() { updateDate(); chartData.redraw(); },1000)

However, the old path doesn't get deleted.

EDIT: Here is a JSFiddle with the the problem I'm seeing. http://jsfiddle.net/namit101/k8kUZ/26/

Comment: Does `.attr("d",stepline(csProg))` work? I've always seen it as `.attr("d",stepline)`.

Comment: It does indeed work.  I'm forgetting the example, but I've seen it used some where too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`enter` and `exit` are only called for newly added data or just removed data respectively. Therefore, `enter` and `exit` will not be executed every time you call `redraw` unless your data has changed, and then, it will only be called for the newly added data or just removed data.

For your example, you need to create a unique identifer for your data so that `D3` knows which paths to remove and which to add. This can be done by passing a function to the `data` method in addition to your `mydata` variable.

```
var cpg = cprog.selectAll("path").data(mydata, function(d) {
    return d.time + "-" + d.value; 
});
```

Here is an updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brantolsen/k8kUZ/31/).

Comment: I am updating the the data structure and calling redraw, but the old path doesn't get erased.  Am I calling it in the wrong way?  (I've updated the questions)

Comment: @user1167650 Is it possible to put a sample into http://jsfiddle.net/ so that people can see the exact problem and the full code?

Comment: @user1167650 Why is it drawing multiple paths? Ideally, it should be a single path per curve. Try inspecting element.

Comment: Ain't there any manual mode where every redraw can be triggered manually (at higher level than D3)? I'm affraid this would generate memory leaks ...

Comment: So if I write `.data(mydata, function(d) { return Math.random(); });` it should re-render everytime I call it, right?

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger Yes, returning a random number for the identifier would cause it to always redraw.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks, but it feels super dirty. I don't understand the clean way to make a redraw from scratch each time...

Answer (score 5):

You should read [Thinking with Joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) if you're having trouble understanding when to use `enter()` and `exit()`. There's also a good tutorial on [Path Transitions](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/) which may help you as well. Without posting your full code, it's tough to recommend more than that.